# Column in custom report disappears

Tags: windows-10, script, powershell-5.0

Script Purpose:
Read audio files and create a Custom report with the name of the songs and the LUFS value of each one.

Problem:
When a song name is too long, the LUFS Value column disappears from the report.

Report without the file with the long name: `Shows the Music and LUFS column.`

```
Music                                                                                           LUFS
------                                                                                          ----
05 - Earth Wind and Fire - September (The Reflex Revision).mp3                                  -9,6
06 - Electric Light Orchestra - Last Train To London (Bootleg Extended Dance Remix).mp3         -9,1
```

Report with the file with the long name: `Only shows the Music column and the LUFS column disappears.`

```
Music                                                                                         
------                                                                                          
05 - Earth Wind and Fire - September (The Reflex Revision).mp3                                  
06 - Electric Light Orchestra - Last Train To London (Bootleg Extended Dance Remix).mp3         
Adele & Ellie Goulding vs. Daft Punk - The Fire Under the Sheets Something About Us (Carlos Serrano Mix...
```

Note above, that in the report, the long name of the song does not appear in full, it only shows `...` at the end.

Script:

```
[decimal]$vLUF = -11.0

$logMatches = Select-String -Path "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\*.*" -Pattern '(?<I>^ +I:) +(?<LUFS>.+)|(?<I>^Input Integrated:) +(?<LUFS>.+)' -List | Select-Object -Property FileName -ExpandProperty Matches
 $results = foreach ($log in $logMatches) {
     $pos = $log.Filename.IndexOf("_")     
     $LUFS = $log.Groups | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "LUFS" }
     [PSCustomObject]@{
         Music = $log.Filename
         LUFS = [decimal]$($LUFS.Value -replace " .*")
        }
}

$vLUFLess = ($vLUF)+ (-0.9)
$vLUFGreat= ($vLUF)+ (-0.5)

$results | Where-Object {($_.LUFS -lt $vLUFLess) -or ($_.LUFS -gt $vLUFGreat) } | Out-File "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\Music LUFS Values Report.txt"
```

How to make the report generate correctly (with both columns) even when there is a song with a long name?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works:

Created the path variable to the txt file:
`$files = "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\Music LUFS Values Report.txt"`

Used the path variable to generate the txt file:

```
$results | Where-Object {($_.LUFS -lt $vLUFpsLess) -or ($_.LUFS -gt $vLUFpsGreat) } | Out-File $files
```